# Nth Derivative of a fucntion

Tags: derivatives

Find the $N^{th}$ derivative of $$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac {1-x}{1+x}}$$

I have got $1^{st}$ derivative as: $\frac{-1}{(1-x)^{1/2}(1+x)^{3/2}}$

and $2^{nd}$ derivative as: $\frac{1-2x}{(1-x)^{3/2}(1+x)^{5/2}}$

and $3^{rd}$ derivative as: $\frac{-6x^2+6x-3}{(1-x)^{5/2}(1+x)^{7/2}}$

I can see how will the denominator gets it form but can you help me with the numerator?

Thanks. :)

Comment: You could write $f^{(n)}(x) = P_n(x)/D_n(x)$ with $D_n$ your denominator and $P_n$ a polynomial satisfying a recurrence relation.

Comment: The third derivative seems wrong : numerator should be $-6 x^2+6 x-3$

Comment: I think i can find D_n(x) but could you help me with P_n(x). Thanks..

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you are right.. found my mistake.. Thanks

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be $\varphi(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}=f(g(x))$ where $f(x)=\sqrt x$ and $g(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+1}=\frac{2}{x+1}-1$.

It's easy to see that
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{\sqrt\pi x^{\frac{1}{2}-n}}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}-n\right)}
$$
amd
$$
g^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n2 \,n!\,(x+1)^{-1-n}
.
$$

Thus, we can use the  Faà di Bruno's formula in the classical form
$$
\varphi^{(n)}(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(x))
=\sum \frac{n!}{m_1!\,m_2!\,\cdots\,m_n!}\cdot
f^{(m_1+\cdots+m_n)}(g(x))\cdot
\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{g^{(j)}(x)}{j!}\right)^{m_j}
$$
where the sum is over all $n$-tuples of nonnegative integers $(m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ satisfying the constraint
$1\cdot m_1+2\cdot m_2+3\cdot m_3+\cdots+n\cdot m_n=n$ or  the Faà di Bruno's formula expressed in terms of [Bell polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html) $B_{n,k}(x_1,\ldots,x_{n−k+1})$
$$\varphi^{(n)}(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(x))= \sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}(g(x))\cdot B_{n,k}\left(g'(x),g''(x),\dots,g^{(n-k+1)}(x)\right).$$

Comment: Just to be clear, isn't it φ(x) = g(f(x))?? If i am not wrong.

Comment: @rndflas sorry, I inverted $f$ and $g$, now it's correct.

Comment: thanks for the help! I got it now.